# display a confirmation django admin view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Will be possible to display a confirmation hearing to modify a record in a table, as is done when you delete a record?

As to modify a record and press the button save this did not request any confirmation or performs the action.

Find out what would have to occupy the `pre_save()`, but I could not make the confirmation hearing

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`formtools` contrib package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/) you'll find `form-preview`, which is a class that lets you load a form, preview it, and then provides hooks to do whatever you would like with the cleaned form data.

It takes care of the following flow:

1. Load a form.
2. Let people fill it in.
3. Show a preview page, where you can edit the form.
4. Confirm button, which you can hook into to do whatever needs to be done with the form.

This would solve your confirmation problem.